# open external application from browser in windows (from a mediawiki page)

Tags: windows, registry, wiki, mediawiki-api

I have installed the media wiki server for my team and I wanted to be able to open external application by just clicking in the browser: These applications are: ldapbrowser, ssh and Remote Desktop.
The idea is to have a list of many IP address and by clicking on them to open the applications directly
I couldn´t find so much information about how to do it and I found it very confusing so I would like to share what works for me after many trials and errors

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to add the following to the windows registry:

- Putty and ssh protocol

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh] @="URL:ssh Protocol" "URL Protocol"="ssh://"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open\command] @="cmd /V:ON /c set params=%1 && set params=!params:ssh://=! && start \"PuTTY\" \"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\putty.exe\" \"!params:/=!\""
```

- LDAP browser

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ldap2] @="URL:LDAP browser <URL:LDAP%20Protocol> " "URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ldap2\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ldap2\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ldap2\shell\open\command] @="cmd /c set url=\"%1\" & call set url=%%url:ldap2:=%% & call start ldapAdmin %%url%%"
```

- Remote desktop

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp] @="URL:Remote Desktop Protocol <URL:Remote%20Desktop%20Protocol> " "EditFlags"=dword:00000002 "URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp\shell\open\command] @="cmd /V:ON /c setlocal && set url=%1 && set url=!url:rdp:=! && set url=!url:,= ! && start mstsc !url!"
```

And add this to your mediawiki text, for example:

```
* [ssh://X.X.X.X some system via SSH]
* [ssh://X.X.X.X some other system SSH]

* <htmltag tagname="a" href="rdp:/v:X.X.X.X" class="my-links">Remote Desktop connection to : X.X.X.X</htmltag>

* <htmltag tagname="a" href="ldap2:/X.X.X.X" class="my-links">LDAP connection to : X.X.X.X</htmltag>
```